# Ceiling Texture brush

Tags: ceiling

Which stipple brush will match this particular ceiling texture?[image]

Comment: I'm no ceiling expert, but that appears to be plaster pulled/sucked down by putting up a rag, squishing it, and pulling it down. ?? Anyone feel free to correct me.

Comment: Why a brush? A 3/8" or 1/2" nap roller should do fine. Otherwise, just about any brush suitable for the (latex?) paint you'll use.

Comment: Thanks for all of the answers, I will experiment with the different tools, methods, and consistency.

Answer (score 3):

This is created by a crow's foot texture brush.  The brush looks like this:

[image]

To see how it's used, refer to [HOW TO TEXTURE (OR RETEXTURE) CEILINGS](http://www.danksandhoney.com/2013/01/how-to-texture-or-retexture-ceilings.html) written by Mallory Danks.

Comment: This is probably the correct answer, but I'd imagine you'll have to experiment around with the brush (or several different brushes of the same style) and the amount of compound used to get an exact (close) match.

Comment: Of course!  There are a few variations one being more circular than what is shown.  And you should experiment with the amount of paint used to get the desired effect.